# Apache Camel route - send data between multiple "to" in xml

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel

I route request to *method1* of bean *myBean1*.This bean return some data and i want send it to next "to" to ejb method like *dataFromMyBean1*. How can i do this? It should look something like this:

```
    <route>
        <from uri="netty4:tcp://0.0.0.0:9555?textline=true&amp;sync=true"/> 
        <to uri="bean:myBean1?method=method1"/>
        <to uri="ejb:beanName?method=methodName1(arg1, arg2, arg3, dataFromMyBean1)"/>
    </route>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about bean parameter binding, how to specify args in method signatures.

- http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html

There is some limitation as what you can specify. See the section *Parameter binding using method option* on that link.

If you need something more, then you can call the bean from real java code, or possible use an inlined groovy script etc.